# Use jQuery to select a div inside an ASP.NET MVC form

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I find `gridContent` if it is located in a form rendered from `BeginForm()` as below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null,null,FormMethod.Get,new{id = "searchByCriteria"})){
    <table>
        @* blah blah blah *@
    </table>
    <div id = "buttons">
        @* blah blah blah *@ 
    </div>
    <div id="gridContent"> Find this section</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form will have the id `searchByCriteria`.. So use this

`$("#searchByCriteria #gridContent")`

or

`$("#searchByCriteria").find("#gridContent")`

Comment: Kind of off topic but if I want to erase the content inside `gridContent` can I do `document.getElementById($("#searchByCriteria").find("#gridContent")).innerHTML = "";`?

Comment: Don't mix jQuery and javascript for targeting DOM elements. This should do `$("#searchByCriteria #gridContent").html("")`